# Can every "not-too-big" differential field be thought of as actually consisting of functions?

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, differential-algebra

*Now also [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441268/can-every-not-too-big-differential-field-be-thought-of-as-actually-consisting):*

Let $\sim$ denote the "no-disagreement" relation between partial functions: $f\sim g$ iff there is no $x$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are each defined and are distinct.

Say that a [differential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra#Differential_field) $\mathcal{K}=(K;0,1,+,\cdot,\partial)$ is **fully concrete** iff there is some way to assign, to each $\alpha\in K$, a partial function $\pi_\alpha$ on the constant subfield $C(\mathcal{K}):=\{\gamma\in K:\partial\gamma=0\}$ such that:

- For $\gamma\in C(\mathcal{K})$, $\pi_\gamma$ is $\lambda x. \gamma$.
- $\pi$ is injective-up-to-$\sim$, in the sense that $\pi_\alpha\not\sim\pi_\beta$ whenever $\alpha\not=\beta$.
- $\mathcal{K}$ is closed-up-to-$\sim$ under composition, in the sense that for each $\alpha,\beta\in K$ there is a unique $\gamma\in K$ such that $\pi_\gamma\sim\pi_\alpha\circ\pi_\beta$. (Since the functions involved are partial, this falls short of $\pi_\gamma=\pi_\alpha\circ\pi_\beta$.) I'll write "$\alpha\circ\beta$" for this unique $\gamma$.
- The field operations commute-up-to-$\sim$ with $\pi$, in the sense that $$\lambda x.\pi_{\alpha\star\beta}(x)\sim\lambda x.[\pi_\alpha(x)\star\pi_\beta(x)]$$ for $\star\in\{+,\cdot\}$.
- The chain rule holds, in the sense that $\partial(\alpha\circ\beta)=[(\partial\alpha)\circ\beta]\cdot\partial\beta$.

Finally, say that a differential field is **concrete** iff it is a sub-differential field of a fully concrete differential field with the same constant subfield.

The difference between concreteness and fully concreteness takes Qiaochu Yuan's comment below into account: it's pretty clear that the differential field $\mathbb{C}(f)$ with $\partial(f)=f$ should be "concretizable" with $\pi_f=\lambda x.e^x$, but in order to get closure under composition we need to pass to a larger family of functions. We could have weakened the compositionality requirement instead - e.g. require only that whenever $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in K$ have $\pi_\gamma\sim\pi_\alpha\circ\pi_\beta$ then there is a $\theta\in K$ with $\pi_\theta\sim\pi_{\partial\alpha}\circ\pi_\beta$ and $\partial(\gamma)=\partial(\theta)\cdot\partial\beta$ - but thinking in terms of "no-additional-constants" extensions seems more natural.

Concreteness seems like a natural property to consider for differential fields, but I haven't run into it before (I'm very new to differential fields though) and it's not obvious to me how common or rare it is. To get things started:

> Suppose $\mathcal{K}$ is a differential field with the same cardinality as its constant subfield. Must $\mathcal{K}$ be concrete?

I'm also generally interested in any sources about concreteness, or any variant thereof - generally, when can a differential field be "faithfully" thought of as consisting of partial functions over its constant subfield?

Comment: Consider the differential field $\mathbb{C}(f)$ equipped with the derivation $\partial f = f$. The obvious way to concretize this is to take $f(z) = e^z$, but the result isn't closed under composition, since $\mathbb{C}(f)$ consists of rational functions of $e^z$ and this doesn't include $e^{e^z}$ or further iterated compositions. But I would call this a concretization in any reasonable sense, so it seems to me that closure under composition is too much to ask for.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Good point. I've edited to take this into account; let me know what you think!

Comment: The use of $\lambda x$ randomly in the definitions is mysterious to me. E.g. what on Earth is meant by $\pi_\gamma$ “is $\lambda x.\gamma$”?

Comment: @FShrike $\lambda x.\gamma$ is the constant function sending everything to $\gamma$. This is a literally different "thing" than $\gamma$ itself, and even if "$\pi_\gamma=\gamma$" would be correctly construed that expression is incorrect. There's nothing random about the $\lambda$-notation, it's [standard function-building notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Comment: Ah. Lambda calculus. I have never ever needed to use that, so I wasn't familiar with it

Comment: Also, are these $\pi_\bullet$ functions $C(K)\to K$?

Comment: @FShrike No, $C(\mathcal{K})\rightarrow C(\mathcal{K})$ ("function on $C(\mathcal{K})$"). This should be clear also from the motivating examples: we don't consider rational functions to be maps from reals to rational functions, after all.

Comment: To me, "function on [-]" only suggests the domain is [-]

Comment: (it is an interesting question anyway, now that I understand your setup. +1)

Comment: For a counterexample, perhaps something like the field of [grid-based] transseries; maybe even just the Levi-Civita numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_field

Comment: @GEdgar Is it clear that any of those are not concrete?